# Is there any way to controll the latency of FCM messgae delivery within 1 minute?

Tags: android, firebase

The latency from Firebase to an android device that is installed our app vary every time. Normally, the FCM High priority message is received by android device 20 seconds to 
50 seconds after our server request FCM to send messages. Once in a while, the latancy is between 1 min to 2 mins and our customer do not accept the latency over 1 minute.

My questions are:
1) Is the over 1 minute latency common for FCM message?
2) Is it common FCM behavior that timing of notification vary each time the message sent by FCM?
3) Is there any way to controll the latency of FCM messgae delivery within 1 minute?

Answer (score 1):

You should Read [**`FCM messages`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options).

> FCM usually delivers messages immediately after they are sent.
>   However, this might not always be possible. For example, if the
>   platform is Android, the device could be turned off, offline, or
>   otherwise unavailable. Or FCM might intentionally delay messages to
>   prevent an app from consuming excessive resources and negatively
>   affecting battery life.

When this happens, FCM stores the message and delivers it as soon as it's feasible. While this is fine in most cases, there are some apps for which a late message might as well never be delivered. For example, if the message is an incoming call or video chat notification, it is meaningful only for a short period of time before the call is terminated. Or if the message is an invitation to an event, it is useless if received after the event has ended.

Comment: I read the manual from the link you gave me and I noticed that our engineer had not set TTL and the TTL was set default. I reported the information to our engineers but no engineer have had time to fix it. I am sorry but I cannot say your answer will fix the problem. But I guess it will solve the issue.